# What is causing popen to segfault?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, pipe, popen

I have tried searching for this online, but I haven't had any luck. I'm hoping there are some theories here. We were able to get our code to crash on this line:

```
pipe = popen(cmd, "w");
```

cmd has recently been allocated, but the allocation was checked to verify that it wasn't null and inspecting the core file reveals that it is indeed a valid string. I'm curious what else would cause `popen` to segfault if the parameters passed in are valid ? Will `popen` segfault if there are no more available file descriptors on the system? Are there any other things I can look into for why this might've failed?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a short example program that demonstrates a seg fault?

Comment: what is the numeric value of `pipe` upon return?

Comment: @levengli I suspect that if a segfault is happening inside `popen`, it doesn't return.

Comment: i'd be tempted not to use the word 'pipe' as the var name as its the name of an in-built function used for creating a pair of file descriptors

Comment: You are right @EricFinn. I thought that using the result was causing the segfault.

Comment: try to check value of _errno_ and make sure that `cmd` is a char pointer and it will be better if you pass command directly in `" "`.

Comment: @Dayalrai The command has to be built at run-time, but it is a char pointer and a valid one at that.

Comment: @BenJ we actually name it outmail not pipe, I just changed the name in the snippet I posted.

Comment: @simonc I can't readily reproduce it each time. The code is simply to call pipe like that, but when we are at a high enough usage level in our daemon, we get it to crash. That is why I'm wondering if popen() can segfault because it doesn't have any more available file descriptors.

Comment: @dbeer and value of errno???whenever it gets crash.

Comment: Sometimes a program doesn't crash due to memory falults not at the line where the real error occurs but somewhere later in a piece of code that is 'totally innocent'. Maybe it's such a kind of problem (sorry you, of so)

Comment: @simonc can `errno` from core be trusted? @dbeer, can you provide what `errno` says in core files?

Comment: Have you tried a minimal code example?  i.e.:
`fp = popen("cat", "w");`
`assert (NULL!=fp);`
`pclose(fp);`

Comment: @Dayalrai I cannot read the errno. When I print errno in gdb it says "You can't do that without a process to debug." Other variables are valid. I wouldn't expect the value stored in errno to be correct on a crash anyway.

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell the program is segfaulting on that first line. It doesn't ever return from the call to popen().

Comment: Here are two test cases that might help: 1. Pass a string literal into your popen: `pipe = popen("cat", "w");` if that doesn't fail then _In a separate program_ put the code where you're allocating and assigning cmd and this popen statement.  If neither of these fail then you most likely have a memory corruption issue somewhere higher in your code.

Comment: Try to print (or log) `cmd` before calling popen. If it crashes on printing, it's `cmd` fault, otherwise it is `popen` fault.

Comment: try to use some debugger like gdb or valgrind to get specific line of crash.

Comment: @dbeer - In case it is still relevant, I have encounter a similar situation when using `popen` to run `modinfo`. When the latter was invoked, it tried to inspect details of a kernel modile which it could not found, thus an error was rised - and while trying to "output" the relevant message further on, it "internally" segfault itself. The scenario took place on a red hat enterprise linux server release 6.9 (santiago) machine. I found this link that seems to approve the issue: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/394983.  Hope it helps anyone.

Comment: @GuyAvraham I solved this problem some time ago, but I didn't post the answer because the question got closed as off-topic (despite it being clearly relevant). I no longer remember how I solved this issue.

Comment: I just got identical issue. The problem ended up being in completely different place with writing beyond allocated memory: didn't allocate one byte for string null-termination